# On hover text style is not applying based on the Material State

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to change the text color based on the Material state, but it is not updating as expected, below is the code which I implemented

On hover, I'm trying to update text color as blue but not updating

```
ElevatedButton(
    style: ButtonStyle(backgroundColor:
        MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((Set<MaterialState> states) {
      if (states.contains(MaterialState.hovered)) {
        return Colors.green;
      }
    }), textStyle:
        MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((Set<MaterialState> states) {
      var style =
          const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, color: Colors.white);
      if (states.contains(MaterialState.hovered)) {
        return style.apply(color: Colors.blue);
      } else {
        return style.apply(color: Colors.white);
      }
    })),
    onPressed: () {},
    child: Text('heloo'));
```

Here is a snapshot of the button on hover, where the background color changes, but the text color remains unchanged.
[image: on hover]

Answer (score 2):

As the comments on the textStyle object states:

> The color of the [textStyle] is typically not used directly, the
> [foregroundColor] is used instead.

```dart
ElevatedButton(
  style: ButtonStyle(
    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(
        (Set<MaterialState> states) {
      if (states.contains(MaterialState.hovered)) {
        return Colors.green;
      }
      return null;
    }),
    foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(
        (Set<MaterialState> states) {
      if (states.contains(MaterialState.hovered)) {
        return Colors.blue;
      } else {
        return Colors.white;
      }
    }),
  ),
  onPressed: () {},
  child: const Text(
    'heloo',
    style: TextStyle(
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
    ),
  ),
);
```